# Is Wonder Woman canonically bisexual?

Tags: dc, wonder-woman

I haven't caught up on the DC movies, but I'm fairly certain that Diana isn't established to be bisexual in them (although I could be wrong).  But I've heard people talking about how she's canonically bisexual in the comics.  Is this accurate?  Is this referring to a certain comic version of her?

Comment: It's heavily hinted at, between winks at how there's just women on the island and they're unlikely to be 100% chaste to mentions of the "tie-up games" the girls engage in, but as far as I know, the only explicit female lovers Wonder Woman has had have been in alternate universes. "Ask...The Question: Have Any Comics Presented Wonder Woman as Bisexual?" https://www.dcuniverseinfinite.com/news/ask-question-have-any-comics-presented-wonder-woman-bisexual/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In relation to ***[Wonder Woman: Year One](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman:_Year_One_(Collected))***, then yes, it's absolutely confirmed that Diana has had multiple lesbian relationships in the past. She also engages in a sexual relationship with Steve Trevor.

[image]

The writers have confirmed that she's 100% "queer" (e.g. bisexual)

> **Matt Santori:** *I’m going to start off simple and to the point. The Wonder Woman that you and Nicola have introduced to us in “Year One” — is she queer?*
>
> **Greg Rucka:** *How are we defining “queer?” You’re applying a term specifically and talking to an ostensibly cis male (and white to boot), so “queer” to me may not be the same as it is to an out gay man. So, tell me what queer is.*
>
> **MSG:** *Fair enough. For the purposes of this conversation, **I would define “queer” as involving, although not necessarily exclusively, romantic and/or sexual interest toward persons of the same gender.** It’s not the full definition, but it’s the part I’m narrowing in on here.*
>
> **GR:** *Then, yes.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Exclusive Interview: Greg Rucka on Queer Narrative and WONDER WOMAN](http://www.comicosity.com/exclusive-interview-greg-rucka-on-queer-narrative-and-wonder-woman/)</sup></sub>